# Wordpress get_the_post_thumbnail(); issue

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a custom theme in wordpress and having problems displaying  `get_the_post_thumbnail();` Tried it a few different ways without success. It's echoing 'no thumbnail' even though there is a thumbnail

```
<?php
/* 
* Template Name: Blog Page
*/
get_header(); ?>

<div class="top-image">
<div class="headlines-2">
        <h1 class="big">blog</h1>

        </div>
        </div>

<div id="primary" class="col-md-12">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
 <div class="news">
 <?php               
$args = array(
'cat' => 9,
    'posts_per_page' => '70'
);

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );


// The Loop
if (has_post_thumbnail($_post->ID, 'thumbnail') ){
$photo = get_the_post_thumbnail($_post->ID, 'thumbnail');
echo  '<div class="section1-2singlephoto">' . $photo . '</div>';
}

else {
echo 'no Thumbnail';
}
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
 while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $the_query->the_post();
echo '<div class="boxed col-md-4">';
echo '<h2 class="titles">' . get_the_title() . '</h2>';
 echo '<span class="rule"></span>';
     echo '<div class="author-info">'. get_the_date() .'<br>' .
   get_the_author_link() .'</div>'; 
  echo get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() 
  );

            echo "</div>";

        }
       } else {
// no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();?>
</div>


    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->

<?php

get_footer();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're checking for a thumbnail outside of your custom post loop so I'm assuming you're expecting the thumbnail to be applied to the page itself and not the individual posts.

The first issue you have is `$_post` isn't defined so `has_post_thumbnail()` will always evaluate to false.

It's quite common to see `$post` used instead but you'd first want to include `global $post;`.

Secondly, as another user has already pointed out, `has_post_thumbnail` doesn't accept more than one argument (it's unlikely to cause a problem though).

**Example 1 - show the page's thumbnail:**

Change this -

```
if (has_post_thumbnail($_post->ID, 'thumbnail') ){
    $photo = get_the_post_thumbnail($_post->ID, 'thumbnail');
    echo  '<div class="section1-2singlephoto">' . $photo . '</div>';
}

else {
    echo 'no Thumbnail';
}
```

To this -

```
global $post;

if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post ) ) {
    $photo = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'thumbnail' );
    echo  '<div class="section1-2singlephoto">' . $photo . '</div>';
} else {
    echo 'no Thumbnail';
}
```

**Example 2 - show individual post thumbnails:**

Place the following **inside** your post loop -

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // note the removal of all args.

    // here we switch from using an ID to null
    $photo = get_the_post_thumbnail( null, 'thumbnail' );
    echo  '<div class="section1-2singlephoto">' . $photo . '</div>';
} else {
    echo 'no Thumbnail';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try it.

$post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($_post->ID);
$post_thumbnail_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $post_thumbnail_id );

" />

Answer (score 0):

has_post_thumbnail only accepts one parameter, the post object (or post id).

remove **, 'thumbnail'** so it's just:

```
if (has_post_thumbnail($_post->ID) ){
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_post_thumbnail/